# C++ Assigning array size as variable and assign value to the variable at runtime?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am really new to C++ programming so please pardon my silly question.

I have an array that looks like this:

```
double myarray [15][20000]; // Works ok but stack overflow error if I change 15 to about 200
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
double myarray [total][20000];
```

then at runtime I want user to input the value of **total**:

```
cin>>total
```

Please advice on how to acheive this and what is the best practice to solve this and avoid stack overflow.

Thanks.

Comment: You're getting stack overflow errors because the array is too big for the stack. You should allocate it on the heap instead (best done with a vector, as Seth shows). Also, variable-length arrays are not part of standard C++ IIRC. That's another plus for vectors.

Comment: ya, Seth example solved the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `vector` of `vector`s:

```
int total;

cin >> total;

//                                      (1)                        (2)
std::vector<std::vector<double>> myVec(total, std::vector<double>(20000));
// (1) is the first dimension and (2) is the second dimension
```

And you can use them just like an array, and you won't get a stack overflow:

```
myVec[0][4] = 53.24;
cout << myVec[0][4];
```

And you can even make them bigger on the fly if you need to.

You're getting a stack overflow because the stack is usually pretty small and you are trying to allocate too big an array on it. `vector` uses dynamically allocated memory on the free store which is usually *much* bigger and won't give you an overflow error.

Also, in C++ the size of static arrays must be known at compile time which is why you can't read in a number and use that, whereas with `vector`s you can resize them at runtime.

Comment: A vector of `std::array` (equivalently the 3rd-party `boost::array` pre-0x) is a better match for what OP described, but not necessarily what OP really wants.